# Turn pixel image into scalable vector graphic in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, vector-graphics, smoothing

Please note that im not interested in any kind of interpolation algorithms where you expand the amount of pixels and interpolate the new values.

I want to leave the world of pixel based images and am looking for some scalable vector image solution.

Is there a way to turn a pixel image in a ggplot into a color meshed smooth vector graphic?

The following pictures demonstrate what im aiming for.

[image]

and then smooth it out.

[image]

The images are taken from the following wikipedia article [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation)

Please note that the original images from the article are SVG files. You can zoom in as much as you want and you always have smooth color transitions and no edges.

Some additional images and infos: [HERE2](http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=1554)

Here is some example Data of something that meets the first image "nearest"

```
library(ggplot2)
n = 5
pixelImg <- expand.grid(x=1:n,y=1:n)
pixelImg$value <- sample(1:n^2,n^2,replace = T)

ggplot(pixelImg, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#FFCd94", "#FF69B4", "#FF0000","#4C0000","#000000"))
```

If not in ggplot is there a way to do it outside of ggplot?

Comment: in python there is some good looking stuff: http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the `ggsave()` function. It supports `.svg` files for vector graphics.

Comment: am installing the package. i dont believe i get the above mentioned interpolation effect by just exporting to svg. but we'll see :-)

Comment: Yes, this is not an answer to my question rather to the question: how to export ggplot to svg file.

Comment: I high-res svg may solve your problem. I'm not sure of any file spec that handles interpolated colors. You may try PDF output via ggsave as well.

Comment: the color meshing need "special coding" of color gradients etc.The export to filetypes is the smallest problem.